# How do I change the font size to export the pdf in datatables plug in

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables, font-size

How do I change the font size to export the pdf at [datatables plug in](http://datatables.net)? 
I looked at the sources and could not find where does it!

any body can help me??
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Adam stated, you must modify the action script. In TableTools 2.0.1 the file i the one that Adam stated.
In the action script Fonts are defined on line 212 for the title:

```
        pdf.setFont( new CoreFont(FontFamily.HELVETICA), 14 );//14 is the font size
        if ( title != "" )
        {
            pdf.writeText(11, title+"\n");
        }
```

and on line 218 for the other text

```
        pdf.setFont( new CoreFont(FontFamily.HELVETICA), 11 );
        if ( message != "" )
        {
            pdf.writeText(11, message+"\n");
        }
```

There is full reference for the library used to generate the PDF (i point out the font-part) here : http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/org/alivepdf/fonts/FontFamily.html

After you have modified the action script you must compile a new copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf with the command found on top of the action script file:
Compile using: mxmlc --target-player=10.0.0 -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -library-path+=lib ZeroClipboardPdf.as

You'll need the Flex 4 SDK to build the SWF - which you can get free from the Adobe open source pages.

I tried it and it works.

You should always check out http://datatables.net/forums/ also, i found [this](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=4498&page=1) that helped me compile the file!

hope it helps

Comment: In addition: for Flex SDK version 4+ change --target-player part to `--target-player=11.1.0` and also change filename from ZeroClipboardPdf.as to `ZeroClipboard.as`

Comment: hey great ,,, but i am new in this .. can you guide me how i can edit " .as " file and save it in " .swf " file ...because i download main " .as " file and edit some front etc and save it in swf file ..but nothing happens...

Answer (score 2):

The font text is rendered  directly in Flash, and can not be modified with CSS. You would need to modify the ActionScript file for TableTools to change the font size.

It is located in

```
<Datatables Location>/extras/TableTools/media/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf.as
```

Comment: yes, but in that file (/extras/TableTools/media/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf.as) i can't find "font.size". how do i change the font size for the pdf, thx

Comment: @bungdito Unfortunately I don't know ActionScript, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

May be its to late to answer this,but i really didnt find any supporting documents from the author or in any other website regarding tabletools syling techniques...no shame to say i really didnt had much knowledge on actionscript at that point and was searching for a solid document online.But all was in vein.In a nut shell this what you have to do to change styling to the generated pdf

1.Download and install flex sdk 4.

2.Take latest AlivePDF.swc

3.Set path and edit the AS file

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience as well. It might help someone like me who doesn't any background in ActionScript.

Key thing is that the there are two versions `ZeroClipboard` class in `as3` folder

- one in ZeroClipboard.as file
- other in ZeroClipboardPdf.as file

It's obvious that we would be working with `ZeroClipboardPdf.as` file, if we want to change the font size for Pdf exports. However, when I tried the command given at the top on this file

```
mxmlc --target-player=11.1 -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -library-path+=lib ZeroClipboardPdf.as
```

Changed `--target-player` to `11.1` as per comment above

I got the following error

```
Error: A file found in a source-path 'ZeroClipboardPdf' must have the same name as the class definition inside the file 'ZeroClipboard'.
```

So here is what I did

- changed file with name 'ZeroClipboard.as' to 'ZeroClipboardNonePdf.as'
- changed file with name 'ZeroClipboardPdf.as' to 'ZeroClipboard.as'

Then, used this command

```
mxmlc --target-player=11.1 -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -library-path+=lib ZeroClipboard.as
```

and it generated a file named `ZeroClipboard.swf` in `as3` folder and I renamed this file to `copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` and used in my project.

Dev Env: Windows 7, Adobe Flex 4.6